# Firebase Dynamic Links Fallback URL from Firebase Console

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, firebase-console

Hi Im using firebase dynamic links in the firebase to my react native project. Therefore I'm creating dynamic links from the console which will redirect the user to ios and android app. But currently, when the link is opened from the web browser it gives an error as to manyredirection. What I need is when the user opens the link from the desktop browser user needs to be redirected to a web page.

```
My Deeplink - https://xxx.page.link/jobplacement?serviceId=13
```

**For ios and android I have given the app to be opened and if the app is not available redirect to the play store or google play.**

How can I provide a fallback URL for desktop browsers?

Comment: Did you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **ofl** for that. so your URL will be like this -
https://custom.page.link/?link=http://custom.com/create-password/?id=123&apn=com.example.test&efr=1&ofl=http://custom.com/create-password/123

That **ofl** will redirect to your browser.

Checkout the doc - https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually#parameters